# Change font colour on Oil Price ticker (HTML & Javascript)

Tags: javascript

A bit vauge I know, but I need to show the change in oil price (> 0 (green)) (< 0 (red))

Its really starting to frustrate me because I just cannot figure out the code.

Below is what I currently have:

```
<div id="stockPrice"><p><strong>TSX: 11.25</strong> (-0.07)</p>
<p><strong>NYSE: 10.67</strong> (0.00)</p>
<p><strong>Brent Crude: 111.11</strong> (-0.55)</p>
<p><strong>Natural Gas: 3.707</strong> (+0.008)</p></div>
<script>
function handleResponse (json) {
$("#stockPrice").empty();
for ( var i = 0; i < json.query.count; i++ ) {        
var xml = xmlDoc = $.parseXML(json.results[i]), $xml = $( xmlDoc ), $symbol= $xml.find("Symbol"), $price = $xml.find("PreviousClose"), $change = $xml.find("Change");  

            var name = $symbol.text();
            if($symbol.text() == "TLM.TO"){
                            name = "TSX";
            } else if($symbol.text()=="TLM"){
                            name = "NYSE";
            } else if($symbol.text()=="BZU13.NYM"){
                            name = "Brent Crude";
            } else if($symbol.text()=="NGN13.NYM"){
                            name = "Natural Gas";
            }
    stockPrice.innerHTML += "<p><strong>"+ name + ": " + $price.text() + "</strong>    ("+$change.text()+")</p>";
    }
}</script>
```

Basically the number in brackets needs to be red if negative and green if positive... pretty easy eh?, and I'm sure straightforward...., so if anyone can help me I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last bit of your JS to (deliberately verbose to illustrate the point clearly)

```
if (parseInt($change.text()) < 0) {
    stockPrice.innerHTML += '<p><strong>'+name+' : '+$price.text()+'</strong><span class="red">('+$change.text()+')</span></p>';
}
else if (parseInt($price.text()) > 0) {
    stockPrice.innerHTML += '<p><strong>'+name+' : '+$price.text()+'</strong><span class="green">('+$change.text()+')</span></p>';
}
else {
    stockPrice.innerHTML += '<p><strong>'+name+' : '+$price.text()+'</strong><span class="blue">('+$change.text()+')</span></p>';
}
```

### CSS

```
.green { color: green; } // > 0
.red   { color: red  ; } // < 0
.blue  { color: blue ; } // zeroes
```

Comment: I marked your reply as the answer, but needed to tweak the code slightly:

if ($change.text() < 0) {
    stockPrice.innerHTML += '<p><strong>'+name+' : '+$price.text()+'</strong><span class="redtext"> ('+$change.text()+')</span></p>';
}
else if ($change.text() > 0) {
    stockPrice.innerHTML += '<p><strong>'+name+' : '+$price.text()+'</strong><span class="greentext"> ('+$change.text()+')</span></p>';
}
else if ($change.text() == 0) {
    stockPrice.innerHTML += '<p><strong>'+name+' : '+$price.text()+'</strong><span class="bluetext"> ('+$change.text()+')</span></p>';
}


thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

if your $change works, then just do a:

```
var $colorClass = $change >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg";
```

then place:

```
stockPrice.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + name + ': ' + $price.text() + '</strong> <span class="' + $colorClass + '">(' + $change.text() + ')</span></p>';
```

Then you can add the css:

```
.neg {color:red;}
.pos {color:green;}
```